# Menu issue on sitemap page

Tags: 7, routes

[image]

Here is my sitemap structure from my custom sitemap module in which 4 of my menus are displaying. But there are duplicate menu items under **Products** and **About**.  I dont need `MECHANICS`, `INDUSTRIAL` and `SPORTS` under **About**.

How can I remove these menu items, or restrict a specific menu item to display (or not) on the sitemap page?